# Do Onos or any Kharaa take locational Damage?

Tags: natural-selection-2

When shooting an Onos or any other Kharaa where should I aim?

Is there different location damage like on a marine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no locational damage in NS2, at least in the sense that different body parts take different amounts of damage. The damage is the same no matter what part of an enemy you are hitting.

However, the damage of some Alien melee abilities can vary depending on how *accurate* you are. If your crosshairs are directly centered on a Marine (or a structure), the attack will deal full damage. If your target is off-center, it will only 2/3 or 1/3 of normal damage.

This applies to the Skulk and Lerk's bite attack, and the Fade's swipe attack.

### Full damage

[image: Screenshot]

### 2/3 damage

[image: Screenshot]

### 1/3 damage

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: No Way! I was very misinformed, i have been trying to land on people's heads.  Thanks for the clarity.